# Preserve scrolling position in emberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using ember v2.5.0. I want my images page to scroll me where I was before going to details page when I hit the "back" link.

I found this about the problem :

https://dockyard.com/blog/2014/05/05/preserve-scroll-position-in-ember-apps

But when I try to include it in my project, it gives me error

```
routes/index.js: line 130, col 29, 'opts' is defined but never used.
routes/index.js: line 154, col 13, 'position' is defined but never used.
routes/index.js: line 155, col 13, 'viewportHeight' is defined but never used.
```

Also, in the code it says `ThingsView` at the end and I dont know what to write there because I'm using a list not a view.

This is my twiddle :

https://ember-twiddle.com/d88e8e6402b6a437746f3adb5cab85f0?openFiles=router.js%2C

Can anyone help me integrate this into my project or offer me something else? I'm stucked with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduced currentPos property in index controller. and changed this value when scroll event occurs(followed [link](https://dockyard.com/blog/2014/05/05/preserve-scroll-position-in-ember-apps) provided by you). We need to execute the below line on didInsertElement hook,

```
Ember.$(window).scrollTop(this.getWithDefault('currentPos', 0));
```

You please have a look at the sample [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/daa9ed3796ca5209c197382614576974?openFiles=components.image-list.js%2Ctemplates.components.image-list.hbs)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. I was trying to integrate these positioning codes in my index.js which was a mistake, obviously. Great response!

Answer (score 1):

These are not errors. actually these are warning about unused variables or properties. if your code is running well than you can ignore them, or delete all those variables which are not using in your application

Comment: Thanks for the response. I deleted these parts, but the code is still not working. I don't understand why. Should I add these codes to the router.js or my homepage's js? I have so many questions..

Comment: I will solve your problem tomorrow. InshaAllah we will find solution. DontWorry

Comment: Oh awesome! Thank you really really much.